# Python file works differently when lunched from Visual Studio compared to running it with Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, anaconda, python-sounddevice

I'm quite new to python and I've been working on a simple program that would record sound, modify it a bit and then playback it. I wrote it in Visual Studio but this software won't work for me with `sounddevice` and says `No module named '_sounddevice_data'` but when I run it with `python "path to this file"` in Anaconda Prompt it works without any problem. This package is in Visual's python environment which I use- `Anaconda 5.2.0`. On the other hand, running from Anaconda Prompt won't work with tensorflow due to some error which is skipped in Visual `Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2`. What's more, everything works great when I use simple .bat file to run this code :D

```
echo off

CALL  D:\Users\blaze\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat D:\Users\blaze\Anaconda3
python C:\Users\blaze\source\repos\recorder\recorder\recorder.py

echo on
```

I'd be grateful for any help because I just can't understand what is going on.
Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as  tf
import numpy as np
import time
import glob
import os
model=tf.keras.models.load_model("D:\Projekt\ML\save\model.h5py",compile=True)

duration = 100  # seconds
frames = 8192
global a 
a=0

file_list_c = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Check", "*.txt"))
for file_path in file_list_c:
    with open(file_path) as f:       
        datax =np.genfromtxt(file_path)     
        datax=np.reshape(datax,(-1,8192))
        print(model.predict(datax))
        print(np.argmax(model.predict(datax)))

import sounddevice as sd
def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status)
    print(np.argmax(model.predict(np.reshape(indata,(-1,8192)))))
    outdata[:] = indata


with sd.Stream(samplerate=48000,blocksize=8192,channels=1, callback=callback):
    sd.sleep(int(duration*1000))


time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: Please specify how exactly you installed the `sounddevice` module.

Comment: This is not an actual error: `Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2`. It is just a warning that tells you that your CPU could do the calculations even faster if you would compile TensorFlow with appropriate settings. But it should still work correctly, just a little (or not so little?) bit slower.

Comment: Hi @Matthias, I installed the module by typing `conda install -c conda-forge python-sounddevice` in Anaconda Prompt and it can be seen in python environment- https://www.dropbox.com/s/mapk0xr6dsst75h/iten.png?dl=0 Actually, tensorflow accesed from Anaconda Command Prompt has some other errors too which look like that https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9pfbjv5taohgcm/ten.png?dl=0

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know what's going wrong when you launch the script from Visual Studio. As a work-around, you could try to install the `sounddevice` module with `pip` instead of `conda` (un-installing it with `conda` first).

Comment: I don't know too much about lunching .py in Visual Studio, so I can't say anyhing but maybe you know something about using .bat? This way everything is working good, so maybe problem is in Anaconda Command Prompt?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm neither a Windows nor an Anaconda user.